# Define symbol for GCC in Windows

Tags: c, gcc, linker, timestamp, symbols

I try to use a linker symbol for a timestamp with GCC on Windows:

```
gcc.exe -DTIMESTAMP=$(shell "C:/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/date.exe +%s") -E helloworld.c -o test.E
```

But I get the output:

> gcc.exe: error: C:/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/date.exe +s): No such file or
> directory

"C:/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/date.exe +s" on the command line works...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried "gcc.exe -DTIMESTAMP=$(shell C:/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/date.exe +%%s) -E helloworld.c -o test.E" but didn't change anything... Givs me: gcc.exe: error: +%s): No such file or directory

Comment: Are you trying to run this command from a Windows console (the "DOS prompt"/"Command prompt")`?

Comment: Yes. I wrote a bat file to test it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems here:

1. `$()` is not valid command line syntax; it's a Bash feature. You want the `call` command or `cmd /C`
2. `shell` is not a command, batch file, or binary. If you have a subshell with the above it is unnecessary.
3. the percent sign must be escaped with another percent sign `%%`

Here's how you would do it in the command line (not [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)):

```
REM Store the output of date.exe to a tempfile
C:/mingw/msys/1.0/bin/date.exe +%%s > tmpfile

REM Read the file into a variable
set /p formatteddate=<tmpfile

REM Invoke gcc.exe with the variable
gcc.exe -DTIMESTAMP=%formatteddate% ...
```

Comment: Ok. Thx. I understand it, but I don't get it to work. What would be the right call?

Answer (score 0):

All C99 compilers (well, more like all C compilers) -- definitely including GCC and Visual C++ and just about any common C compiler you are likely to ever use already provides macros [`__DATE__` and `__TIME__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html); is there a reason you don't use them?

They expand to string literals referring to the date and time the preprocessor is run. `__DATE__` expands to `"Mmm Dd YYYY"`, for example `"Nov  1 2016"`; `__TIME__` expands to `"hh:mm:ss"`, for example `"23:59:59"`.

If you want a compilation timestamp in your object file, you can use e.g.

```
const char timestamp[] = __DATE__ " " __TIME__ ;
```

in your C code.

---

When you need a shared macro across a larger project, over multiple invocations of the compiler (say, in a Makefile or such), generate a header file that is included in all compilation commands. For example,

```
rm -f timestamp.h
date '+#define TIMESTAMP "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"' > timestamp.h
```

and add flag `-imacros timestamp.h` to the GCC options.

Comment: Yes I did that before. But it only sets the time for the actual file. Not for the whole project. I need a solution where my buildnumber is increased on EACH build...

Comment: @ChristophP.: So, how about the added approach? You could even use `date '+#define BUILDNUMBER %s' > buildnumber.h` (and `-imacros buildnumber.h`) to get it as a decimal number (seconds since Epoch).

Comment: @ChristophP.: To store it into a string, use e.g. `#define STRINGIFY_(x) #x`, `#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_(x)`, and `const char buildnumber[] = STRINGIFY(BUILDNUMBER);`.